# How do I intersect two HashSets while moving values in common into a new set?

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
let mut a: HashSet<T> = HashSet::new();
let mut b: HashSet<T> = HashSet::new();
let mut c: HashSet<T> = a.intersection(&b).collect();
// Error: a collection of type `std::collections::HashSet<T>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&T`
```

I no longer need the non-intersecting values. 
How do I steal/move the data from the sets `a` and `b` into `c` without copying or cloning? Ideally, this would have the theoretically optimal time-complexity: O(min(a, b)).

Comment: It would be useful if you could clarify (1) whether `a` and `b` should retain the non-intersecting values, or it does not matter and (2) what algorithmic complexity you are aiming for.

Answer (score 8):

The aliasing rules imposed by the compiler requires you to move the values back and forth. Values can be drained out of a set, although unconditionally. However, we can send certain values back if we keep track of which should be moved and which should stay in a new set. Afterwards, [`retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.retain) allows us to remove the common values from the second set.

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::Hash;

/// Extracts the common values in `a` and `b` into a new set.
fn inplace_intersection<T>(a: &mut HashSet<T>, b: &mut HashSet<T>) -> HashSet<T>
where
    T: Hash,
    T: Eq,
{
    let x: HashSet<(T, bool)> = a
        .drain()
        .map(|v| {
            let intersects = b.contains(&v);
            (v, intersects)
        })
        .collect();

    let mut c = HashSet::new();
    for (v, is_inter) in x {
        if is_inter {
            c.insert(v);
        } else {
            a.insert(v);
        }
    }

    b.retain(|v| !c.contains(&v));

    c
}
```

Using:

```
use itertools::Itertools;  // for .sorted()

let mut a: HashSet<_> = [1, 2, 3].iter().cloned().collect();
let mut b: HashSet<_> = [4, 2, 3].iter().cloned().collect();

let c = inplace_intersection(&mut a, &mut b);

let a: Vec<_> = a.into_iter().sorted().collect();
let b: Vec<_> = b.into_iter().sorted().collect();
let c: Vec<_> = c.into_iter().sorted().collect();
assert_eq!(&a, &[1]);
assert_eq!(&b, &[4]);
assert_eq!(&c, &[2, 3]);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9020cc133fda82800fe47e7932f6997)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, [similar to E_net4's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55975912/2766908), but this one does not involve draining and then repopulating the first set. IMHO it is slightly easier to read as well.

```
fn inplace_intersection<T>(a: &mut HashSet<T>, b: &mut HashSet<T>) -> HashSet<T>
where
    T: Hash,
    T: Eq,
{
    let mut c = HashSet::new();
    
    for v in a.iter() {
        if let Some(found) = b.take(v) {
            c.insert(found);
        }
    }
    
    a.retain(|v| !c.contains(&v));

    c
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e5bcf032e3c260373873c474c8cd637)

After writing this I realized it could be made even simpler:

```
fn inplace_intersection<T>(a: &mut HashSet<T>, b: &mut HashSet<T>) -> HashSet<T>
where
    T: Hash,
    T: Eq,
{
    let c: HashSet<T> = a.iter().filter_map(|v| b.take(v)).collect();
    
    a.retain(|v| !c.contains(&v));

    c
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c288c0ef82527edf764adefc1f0e5978)

Comment: I would note that if the state of `a` and `b` after intersection do no matter, then the `a.retain(...)` step is unnecessary, and we have an optimally efficient, single-pass, one-liner.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [bitwise and operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-BitAnd%3C%26HashSet%3CT%2C%20S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT%2C%20S%3E) as well:

```
let mut c: HashSet<T> = &a & &b
```

Comment: This does require `T: Clone` however, unlike other answers

Comment: Great answer, and exactly what I wanted to see. Thank you for providing the reference.

Comment: This equivalent to `a.intersection(b).cloned().collect()` (indeed, that's how it's implemented) so it doesn't avoid the reallocation.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you can take ownership over the sets themselves and don't care about retaining the non-intersecting values in the other sets, you can do the following:

```
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn intersection<T: Eq + Hash>(a: HashSet<T>, b: &HashSet<T>) -> HashSet<T> {
    a.into_iter().filter(|e| b.contains(e)).collect()
}
```

This takes the elements in a which are contained in b and collects them into a new HashSet